# Unable to connect to remote couchbase

Tags: java, couchbase

I am attempting to connect to Couchbase v2.2.0 over a network. I am able to ping the port and can even get stuff using curl. But when I try and connect using my Java application (which uses couchbase-client v1.4.7) I get the following error:

```
2016-03-16 10:37:38.788 INFO com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection:  Node for key "Source Category" is not active (yet). Queueing up for retry and checking for stale configuration.
2016-03-16 10:37:38.794 INFO com.couchbase.client.vbucket.provider.BucketConfigurationProvider:  Reconnect attempt 1, waiting 0ms
2016-03-16 10:37:39.297 WARN com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP:  Timed out while reading configuration over HTTP
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
        at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP.readToString(ConfigurationProviderHTTP.java:420)
        at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP.readPools(ConfigurationProviderHTTP.java:206)
        at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP.getBucketConfiguration(ConfigurationProviderHTTP.java:143)
        at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP.subscribe(ConfigurationProviderHTTP.java:321)
        at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.provider.BucketConfigurationProvider.monitorBucket(BucketConfigurationProvider.java:368)
        at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.provider.BucketConfigurationProvider.access$900(BucketConfigurationProvider.java:64)
        at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.provider.BucketConfigurationProvider$HttpProviderRefresher.run(BucketConfigurationProvider.java:622)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-03-16 10:37:39.299 WARN com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP:  Connection problems with URI http://192.168.XX.XX:8091/pools ...skipping
java.io.IOException: Timed out while reading configuration over HTTP
        at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP.readToString(ConfigurationProviderHTTP.java:445)
        at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP.readPools(ConfigurationProviderHTTP.java:206)
        at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP.getBucketConfiguration(ConfigurationProviderHTTP.java:143)
        at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP.subscribe(ConfigurationProviderHTTP.java:321)
        at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.provider.BucketConfigurationProvider.monitorBucket(BucketConfigurationProvider.java:368)
        at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.provider.BucketConfigurationProvider.access$900(BucketConfigurationProvider.java:64)
        at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.provider.BucketConfigurationProvider$HttpProviderRefresher.run(BucketConfigurationProvider.java:622)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
        at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP.readToString(ConfigurationProviderHTTP.java:420)
        ... 7 more
```

Which is very unhelpful. I realise this is not a lot to go on but any suggestions of common problems that this could be symptomatic of would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Our java code:

```
new CouchbaseClient(baseList, bucketName, pwd).get("Source Category");
```

Comment: Please add at least the code you are trying to run in order to connect...

Comment: Hi @RoiKatz, I've edited my question to include the offending Java code. Thanks for taking an interest in our problem.

Comment: I can see that.
but you are try to connect quite wrong
check the [docs](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/java-2.2/java-intro.html)
and [here](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/java-2.2/managing-connections.html)

Comment: I'm having the same issue now after moving servers to new ip addresses. Anybody was success on fixing this issue? I have change the ip address in couch base configuration xml file